# Mapping an entity to more than one table (EF4, WCF RiaServices) - Internationalization

Tags: internationalization, entity-framework-4

if I understood several other posts correctly it's currently not possible to map an entity to more than one table if they do not share the same primary key.

Is this still true? What I'm wondering is how internationalization should be handled with the db design below and EF.

I've a internationalized db where texts are stored in separate tables.
e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE Product(
 ProductID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 ProductGroupID int NOT NULL,
 ...
 CONSTRAINT PK_Product PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 ProductID ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON PRIMARY
) ON PRIMARY

CREATE TABLE Product_i18n(
 ProductID int NOT NULL,
 LanguageID int NOT NULL,
 ProductName nvarchar(150) NULL,
 Description nvarchar(max) NULL,
 ...
 CONSTRAINT PK_Product_i18n PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 ProductID ASC,
 LanguageID ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON PRIMARY
) ON PRIMARY
```

So the product consists of two tables. In the table Product the language independent part is stored and in the table Product_i18n the language dependend part is stored.
The two tables are physically linked with a 1:n association, but logically it's a 1:1 association because I always need one language at a certain operation.

Therefore I would like to combine the two tables in a single entity Product which consists of the columns

- ProductID
- ProductGroupID
- LanguageID
- ProductName
- Description ...

If this would be possible I could keep the internationalized table out of my model to make it more clear.

Is this possible with EF4. Any guidance and experiences with internationalization to solve this issue are welcome.

Thanks a lot

Uwe

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are still having the problem, but you can solve it using a view for your products, more accurate, one view for each language.

Comment: You could use a parameterized view, which would probably be better and allow for easy addition of new cultures.